# How can i close image file that is created from "ironbarcode" barcode generator

Tags: c#, wpf, filehandle, ironbarcode

I use nuGetPacket ironBarCode to create a code128 barcode, it works fine, i load the image to a flowdocument in a wpf usercontrol. I want to delete the image file after i have loaded it into the application but the file is locked - how can i close the file handle- code:

```
            Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
        
             BarcodeWriter.CreateBarcode(ApplicationHandler.TransactionHandler
             .CurrentTransaction.TransactionNumber.ToString()
                            , BarcodeWriterEncoding.Code128).ResizeTo(100, 50)
                                    .SaveAsImage(PrintHandler.GetBinCatalogFilePath() + g + 
              "Code128.jpeg");


        Code128.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(PrintHandler.GetBinCatalogFilePath() + g + 
       "Code128.jpeg"));
```

Comment: I found the answer - i had to set - Code128.source = null,and the close the wpf window correct. After that i could delete the image file !

Comment: That isn't necessary. Just make sure you create the BitmapImage in a way that does not lock the file.

Comment: thank you clemens why dont you show how?

Comment: Because that is already shown in the answer to the duplicate question.